A problem with a function when executing python code from within R
I am executing a Python code from R using the reticulate package
After importing the relevant packages (pandas, datetime,wbdata) in R I execute the python script using py_run_file(). It seems that R can not recognise the "data_date"  in  wbdata.get_dataframe()
These are the warings that I get
Error in py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert) : 
  TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'data_date'
Run `reticulate::py_last_error()` for details.


Python Exception Message ────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "World_BankM.py", line 50, in <module>
    data = wbdata.get_dataframe(indicators, country=country_1,  data_date=(start_date, end_date),convert_date=True)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SA~1\DOCUME~1\VIRTUA~1\R-RETI~1\Lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 231, in fun
    args, kw = fix(args, kw, sig)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SA~1\DOCUME~1\VIRTUA~1\R-RETI~1\Lib\site-packages\decorator.py", line 203, in fix
    ba = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SA~1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PYTHON~1\Lib\inspect.py", line 3273, in bind
    return self._bind(args, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\SA~1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\PYTHON~1\Lib\inspect.py", line 3262, in _bind
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: got an unexpected keyword argument 'data_date'

── R Traceback ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
    ▆
 1. └─reticulate::py_run_file("WorldBankMacro.py")
 2.   └─reticulate:::py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert)
See `reticulate::py_last_error()$r_trace$full_call` for more details.
> reticulate::py_last_error()$r_trace$full_call
[[1]]
py_run_file("World_BankM.py")

[[2]]
py_run_file_impl(file, local, convert)

If I put "convert_date" before "data_date", I get the same warning for convert_date. Any ideas why?

The only get_dataframe I could find is in the client module and it doesn't have data_date parameter. Did you try running the Python code directly to see if it works? If the issue is in the Python code you should post it.

it is the function "wbdata.get_dataframe". The code in pyton runs just fine

see for example here https://deepnote.com/app/econ-growth/3-Working-with-World-Development-Indicators-Duplicate-26fa81bc-20b7-4538-a32b-76b89735cfb7

This example use wbdata==0.2.0, it's from 11 years ago. You probably have versions mismatch.

OK, that makes sense. Thank you a lot

Would it be possible to use the  versio of python that corresponds to wbdata==0.2.0?

I'm sure it is, but I don't know how to tell R to use specific Python version.

Can we do that within the Python code and then run it through R?

If R doesn't allow you to download specific versions you need them installed on your machine.

ok thank you very much

There are number of World Bank API client packages for R (worldbank, WDI, wbstats, maybe few others) , is there a reason why you need to use specific version of wbdata`` though reticulateinstead?  To my understating wbdata` 0.2 was using API v1 which is not live anymore - https://datahelpdesk.worldbank.org/knowledgebase/articles/889392-about-the-indicators-api-documentation.
